# If $M, N$ are normal subgroups in a group $G$ with $M \cap N = 1$, then $mn =nm $ for all $m\in M $ and $n\in N $

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

If $M, N$ are normal subgroups in a group $G$ with $M \cap N = 1$, then $mn =nm $ for all $m\in M $ and $n\in N $, and also show that if $MN =G $ then $G \cong M * N $.

I would really appreciate it if someone could show me a rigorous proof for both of these. Shouldn't the first one be obvious from the definition of normal subgroup? As for the second, how do we draw out the isomorphism?

Comment: Well, $mnm^{-1}n^{-1}=(mnm^{-1})n^{-1}\in N$ and a similar argument shows it is also in $M$ so...

Comment: Are you able to "show [...] a rigorous proof" for the first from "the definition of normal subgroup"?  For the second, you have exactly one fact relating elements of ($M$ and $N$) and elements of $G$; the isomorphism must be there.  What do you think it is?

Comment: The symbol for direct product is $\times$ whereas $*$ is for free product.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to show this is by means of commutators: for subsets $\;A,B\;$ of a group $\;G\;$ , define

$$[A,B]=\langle\,[a,b]:=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab\;|\;a\in A,\,b\in B\,\rangle$$

Be sure you can prove that $\;N\lhd G\iff [A,N]\le N\;$ for all $\;A\subset G\;%$ , and thus we have that

$$[N,M]\le N\cap M=1\iff\forall\,n\in N,\,m\in M,\;\;1= [n,m]=n^{-1}m^{-1}nm\iff nm=mn$$

Comment: How would you show the isomorphism?

Comment: @MatthijsBjornlund  I believe you can do that by yourself: since $\;G=mn\;,\;\;m\in M,\,n\in N\;$ **and this expression is unique** (why?), you can map $$G=MN\to M\times N\;,\;\;g=mn\mapsto (m,n)\;$$ Prove the above is a group isomorphism...